# How to import style files from different directories when specifying `documentclass`

Tags: beamer, pdftex, themes

I have the following in `myfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{mytheme}
```

I need include the theme `mytheme` which resides in a different directory. For example where the  the file `beamerthememytheme.sty` is in `../themefolder/beamerthememytheme.sty` relative to `myfile.tex`.

If I do something like:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{../themefolder/mytheme}
```

I'll end up with an error saying that the file `../themefolder/beamerthememytheme.sty` was not found.

How can I make the correct relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beamer`'s `\usetheme` command is defined as:

```
\newcommand\usetheme[2][]{\beamer@calltheme{#1}{#2}{beamertheme}}
```

and the `beamertheme` string is prepended to the argument of the `\usetheme` command. And the `\beamer@calltheme` command is defined as:

```
  \def\beamer@calltheme#1#2#3{%
    \def\beamer@themelist{#2}
    \@for\beamer@themename:=\beamer@themelist\do
    {\usepackage[{#1}]{#3\beamer@themename}}}
```

so basically the `\usetheme` command is just a wrapper for an `\usepackage`.

So you can rename your file as `mytheme.sty` and `\usepackage{../themefolder/mytheme}`.

Comment: Perfect, I have also noticed that any other style files that are included in `mytheme.sty` need to be imported in the same way from `mytheme.sty` with the path relative to `myfile.tex` and not the path relative to `mytheme.sty`.

Comment: @Kievit Yes, when TeX reads in a file it does not change the current directory to that of the file, so all paths must be relative to the main `.tex` file.